# Mockery and Laravel constructor injection

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, mockery

I am using laravel 5 with php unit to create a laravel package. I have a `Repository`..

```
namespace Myname\Myapp\Repositories;

use Myname\Myapp\Models\PersonModel;

class PersonRepository
{
    protected $personModel;

    public function __construct(PersonModel $personModel)
    {
        $this->personModel = $personModel;
    }

    public function testFunction($var)
    {
        return $this->personModel->find($var);
    }
}
```

..which implements a `Model`.

```
namespace Myname\Myapp\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class PersonModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'person';
}
```

Laravels IoC automatically injects `PersonModel` into the constructor of `PersonRepository`.

I am writing a unit test where I want to mock the `PersonModel` model using mockery so I am not hitting the database during testing.

```
namespace Myname\Myapptests\unit;

use Mockery;

class PersonRepositoryTest extends \Myname\Myapptests\TestCase
{
     /**
     * @test
     */ 
     public function it_returns_the_test_find()
     {
         $mock = Mockery::mock('Myname\Myapp\Models\PersonModel')
            ->shouldReceive('find')
            ->with('var');

         $this->app->instance('Myname\Myapp\Models\PersonModel', $mock);
         $repo = $this->app->make('Myname\Myapp\Repositories\PersonRepository');
         $result = $repo->testFunction('var');

         $this->assert...
     }
}
```

When I run the test I get an error

> 1) Myname\Myapptests\unit\PersonRepositoryTest::it_returns_the_test_find
>   ErrorException: Argument 1 passed to Myname\Myapp\Repositories\PersonRepository::__construct() must be an instance of Myname\Myapp\Models\PersonModel, instance of Mockery\CompositeExpectation given

From what I have read, mockery extends the class it is mocking so there should be no issue injecting the extended class in place of the type hinted parent (PersonModel)

Obviously I am missing something. Other examples explicitly inject the mocked object into the class they are then testing. Laravels IoC is (should be) doing this for me. Do I have to bind anything?

I have a feeling though that the mockery object isn't being created in the way I think (extending PersonModel) otherwise I assume I wouldn't see this error.

Comment: Could you try to import your Model? you are using `PersonModel::class` but I don't see a `use 'Myname\Myapp\Models\PersonModel'`

Comment: @FabioAntunes Updated the code and the error output

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Problem is when you create your mock:

```
$mock = Mockery::mock('Myname\Myapp\Models\PersonModel')
    ->shouldReceive('find')
    ->with('var');
```

So this:

```
$mock = Mockery::mock('Myname\Myapp\Models\PersonModel')
var_dump($mock);
die();
```

Will output something like this: `Mockery_0_Myname_Myapp_Models_PersonModel`

But this:

```
$mock = Mockery::mock('Myname\Myapp\Models\PersonModel')
    ->shouldReceive('find')
    ->with('var');
var_dump($mock);
die();
```

Will output this: `Mockery\CompositeExpectation`

So try doing something like this:

```
$mock = Mockery::mock('Myname\Myapp\Models\PersonModel');
$mock->shouldReceive('find')->with('var');

$this->app->instance('Myname\Myapp\Models\PersonModel', $mock);
$repo = $this->app->make('Myname\Myapp\Repositories\PersonRepository');
$result = $repo->testFunction('var');
```

Comment: @myol glad I helped you out

Comment: just thought i'd add you can do `->with('var')->getMock()` then can declare your mock and fluid chain calls to get the actual mock object

Answer (score 18):

While Fabio gives a [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36724337/1034002), the issue here is really the test setup. [Mockery's mock objects do comply to contracts](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/creating_test_doubles.html#classes-abstracts-interfaces) and will pass `instanceof` tests and type hints in method arguments.

The problem with the original code is that the chain of methods being called end up returning an expectation rather than a mock. We should instead create a mock first, then add expectations to that mock.

To fix it, change this:

```
$mock = Mockery::mock('Myname\Myapp\Models\PersonModel')
    ->shouldReceive('find')
    ->with('var');
```

Into this:

```
$mock = Mockery::mock('Myname\Myapp\Models\PersonModel');
$mock->shouldReceive('find')->with('var');
```

The variable `$mock` will now implement `PersonModel`.

Bonus:

Instead of `'Myname\Myapp\Models\PersonModel'`, use `PersonModel::class`. This is a lot more IDE-friendly and will help you when refactoring code later on.

Comment: Thanks for this response, it's been very helpful. I feel like I'm still missing something, as my mock sitll implements something like Mockery_0_My_Class_Namespace...

I know this is an old post, but maybe you could help me here, instead of me asking the same quesiton...

`$mockCurl = m::mock(HttpRequest::class); $mockCurl->shouldReceive(...`

_RealTag::__construct() must be an instance of westonwatson\HttpRequest or null, instance of Mockery_0_westonwatson_realtag_HttpRequest given_

Comment: Using `PersonModel::class` exactly solved my problem that led me to this question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's fine to fluently chain on the `shouldReceive()` method when creating mocks. If you chain the `getMock()` function to the end of the statement where you create your mock, you will have the instance returned.

So:

```php
$mock = Mockery::mock('Myname\Myapp\Models\PersonModel')
    ->shouldReceive('find')
    ->with('var')
    ->getMock();
```